# Symfony2 refactoring controller logic into a service

Tags: symfony, service, doctrine-orm, refactoring

I'm slowly beginning to understand how things in Symfony2 are working.

I have set up a service which pulls json data from a live feed.

My controller uses this service to pull the data and then persist it to my database, I currently have 3 entities, though there are likely to be quite a few more.

All the logic at present is in `FantasyPro/DataBundle`

I'm currently breaking all sorts of rules, such as the logic for persisting my data is in a controller, so i'm thinking i need to take all this logic and put it into a service which i can use to persist the pulled data into my database via doctrine.

I would like to create this new PersistServce in the DataBundle

As the service will need to use doctrine all the entitys i have as well as the api service i'm not sure how to go about making these available to the service.

It probably worth mentioning that i intend to create commands so that i can run cron jobs to pull this data, in fact i don't think i will need the controller at all as they will only be used internally and not for generating requests.

I have it in a controller right now simply for testing purposes.

Whats the best way to refactor this code into a service?

Heres my messy controller code

```
    <?php

namespace FantasyPro\DataBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\Stadium;
use FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\Team;
use FantasyPro\DataBundle\Entity\Player;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    public function indexAction($name)
    {
        return $this->render('DataBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name));
    }

    /**
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function updateStadiumAction(){
        //get list of stadiums

        $client = $this->container->get('fantasyapi');
        $stadiumData = $client->Stadiums();

        //get the entity manager
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $repo = $em->getRepository('DataBundle:Stadium');
        $log = array();

        $log = $this->addStadiumList( $stadiumData, $repo, $em, $log );

        $em->flush();
        return $this->render('DataBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('log' => $log));
    }

    public function updateTeamAction()
    {

        //get list of teams

        $client = $this->container->get('fantasyapi');
        $teamData = $client->Teams();

        //get the entity manager
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $repo = $em->getRepository('DataBundle:Team');
        $log = array();

        $log = $this->addTeamList( $teamData, $repo, $em, $log, 'Team' );

        $em->flush();
        return $this->render('DataBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('log' => $log));
    }

    public function updatePlayerAction()
    {
        //get the api client
        $client = $this->container->get('fantasyapi');

        //get the manager
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $teamRepo = $em->getRepository('DataBundle:Team');
        $playerRepo = $em->getRepository('DataBundle:Player');
        $log = array();

        //first we need to get a list of teams as players can only be collected via a teamID
        /** @var Team $teams */
        $teams = $client->Teams();
        //var_dump($teams);die;
        //loop through the teams and pull the playerData

        foreach($teams as $team){
            //log the team we are processing
            $logData = ['action' => 'Processing Players for:', 'itemID' => $team['TeamID'], 'itemName' => $team['FullName']];
            $log[] = $logData;

            //get list players on this team
            $players =  $client->Players(['Team' => $team['Key']]);
            //loop through the players

            $log = $this->addPlayerList( $players, $playerRepo, $em, $log, 'Added Active Player' );
        }

        //now get free agents

        $freeAgents = $client->FreeAgents();

        $log = $this->addPlayerList($freeAgents, $playerRepo, $em, $log, 'Free Agent');

        $em->flush();
        return $this->render('DataBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array('log' => $log));

    }

    public function parseDate($dateString)
    {
        if ($dateString) {

            preg_match( '/\/Date\((\d+)([-+])(\d+)\)\//', $dateString, $date );

            $timestamp = $date[1] / 1000;
            $operator  = $date[2];
            $hours     = $date[3] * 36; // Get the seconds

           // $datetime = new \DateTime($timestamp, new \DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));

            $datetime = new \DateTime();
            $datetime->setTimestamp($timestamp);
            $datetime->modify( $operator.$hours.' seconds' );
            $datetime->setTimezone(new \DateTimeZone('UTC'));


            //$datetime->format( 'd-m-Y H:i:s' );
            //var_dump( $datetime );
            //echo('*');
            return ($datetime);
        }
        return(null);
    }

    /**
     * @param Array $players
     * @param $playerRepo
     * @param $em
     * @param Array $log
     *
     * @param String $logTitle
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function addPlayerList( $players, $playerRepo, $em, $log, $logTitle )
    {
        foreach ($players as $player) {
            // Get the current player in the list
            $criteria = array( 'playerID' => $player['PlayerID'] );

            /** @var Player $storedPlayer */
            $storedPlayer = $playerRepo->FindOneBy( $criteria );

            //var_dump($player);
            if ( ! $storedPlayer) {
                //no player exists with the PlayerID passed
                //create a new entry
                /** @var Player $entry */
                $entry = new Player();

                $entry->setTeam( $player['Team'] );
                $entry->setPlayerID( $player['PlayerID'] );
                $entry->setNumber( $player['Number'] );
                $entry->setFirstName( $player['FirstName'] );
                $entry->setLastName( $player['LastName'] );
                $entry->setPosition( $player['Position'] );
                $entry->setStatus( $player['Status'] );
                $entry->setHeight( $player['Height'] );
                $entry->setWeight( $player['Weight'] );
                //need to parse the date on this field
                $entry->setBirthDate( $this->parseDate( $player['BirthDate']));
                $entry->setCollege( $player['College'] );
                $entry->setExperience( $player['Experience'] );
                $entry->setFantasyPosition( $player['FantasyPosition'] );
                $entry->setActive( $player['Active'] );
                $entry->setPositionCategory( $player['PositionCategory'] );
                $entry->setName( $player['Name'] );
                $entry->setAge( $player['Age'] );
                $entry->setExperienceString( $player['ExperienceString'] );
                $entry->setBirthDateString( $player['BirthDateString'] );
                $entry->setPhotoUrl( $player['PhotoUrl'] );
                $entry->setByeWeek( $player['ByeWeek'] );
                $entry->setUpcomingGameOpponent( $player['UpcomingGameOpponent'] );
                $entry->setUpcomingGameWeek( $player['UpcomingGameWeek'] );
                $entry->setShortName( $player['ShortName'] );
                $entry->setAverageDraftPos( $player['AverageDraftPosition'] );
                $entry->setDepthPositionCategory( $player['DepthPositionCategory'] );
                $entry->setDepthPosition( $player['DepthOrder'] );
                $entry->setDepthDisplayOrder( $player['DepthDisplayOrder'] );
                $entry->setCurrentTeam( $player['CurrentTeam'] );
                $entry->setCollegeDraftTeam( $player['CollegeDraftTeam'] );
                $entry->setCollegeDraftYear( $player['CollegeDraftYear'] );
                $entry->setCollegeDraftRound( $player['CollegeDraftRound'] );
                $entry->setCollegeDraftPick( $player['CollegeDraftPick'] );
                $entry->setIsUndraftedFreeAgent( $player['IsUndraftedFreeAgent'] );
                $entry->setHeightFeet( $player['HeightFeet'] );
                $entry->setHeightInches( $player['HeightInches'] );
                $entry->setUpcomingOpponentRank( $player['UpcomingOpponentRank'] );
                $entry->setUpcomingOpponentPositionRank( $player['UpcomingOpponentPositionRank'] );
                $entry->setCurrentStatus( $player['CurrentStatus'] );
                $entry->setUpcomingSalary( $player['UpcomingSalary'] );

                $em->persist( $entry );
                $logData = [ 'action'   => 'Added '.$logTitle,
                             'itemID'   => $player['PlayerID'],
                             'itemName' => $player['Name']
                ];
                $log[] = $logData;
            } else {
                $storedPlayer->setPlayerID( $player['PlayerID'] );
                $storedPlayer->setTeam( $player['Team'] );
                $storedPlayer->setPlayerID( $player['PlayerID'] );
                $storedPlayer->setNumber( $player['Number'] );
                $storedPlayer->setFirstName( $player['FirstName'] );
                $storedPlayer->setLastName( $player['LastName'] );
                $storedPlayer->setPosition( $player['Position'] );
                $storedPlayer->setStatus( $player['Status'] );
                $storedPlayer->setHeight( $player['Height'] );
                $storedPlayer->setWeight( $player['Weight'] );
                //need to parse the date on this field
                $storedPlayer->setBirthDate( $this->parseDate( $player['BirthDate']));
                $storedPlayer->setCollege( $player['College'] );
                $storedPlayer->setExperience( $player['Experience'] );
                $storedPlayer->setFantasyPosition( $player['FantasyPosition'] );
                $storedPlayer->setActive( $player['Active'] );
                $storedPlayer->setPositionCategory( $player['PositionCategory'] );
                $storedPlayer->setName( $player['Name'] );
                $storedPlayer->setAge( $player['Age'] );
                $storedPlayer->setExperienceString( $player['ExperienceString'] );
                $storedPlayer->setBirthDateString( $player['BirthDateString'] );
                $storedPlayer->setPhotoUrl( $player['PhotoUrl'] );
                $storedPlayer->setByeWeek( $player['ByeWeek'] );
                $storedPlayer->setUpcomingGameOpponent( $player['UpcomingGameOpponent'] );
                $storedPlayer->setUpcomingGameWeek( $player['UpcomingGameWeek'] );
                $storedPlayer->setShortName( $player['ShortName'] );
                $storedPlayer->setAverageDraftPos( $player['AverageDraftPosition'] );
                $storedPlayer->setDepthPositionCategory( $player['DepthPositionCategory'] );
                $storedPlayer->setDepthPosition( $player['DepthOrder'] );
                $storedPlayer->setDepthDisplayOrder( $player['DepthDisplayOrder'] );
                $storedPlayer->setCurrentTeam( $player['CurrentTeam'] );
                $storedPlayer->setCollegeDraftTeam( $player['CollegeDraftTeam'] );
                $storedPlayer->setCollegeDraftYear( $player['CollegeDraftYear'] );
                $storedPlayer->setCollegeDraftRound( $player['CollegeDraftRound'] );
                $storedPlayer->setCollegeDraftPick( $player['CollegeDraftPick'] );
                $storedPlayer->setIsUndraftedFreeAgent( $player['IsUndraftedFreeAgent'] );
                $storedPlayer->setHeightFeet( $player['HeightFeet'] );
                $storedPlayer->setHeightInches( $player['HeightInches'] );
                $storedPlayer->setUpcomingOpponentRank( $player['UpcomingOpponentRank'] );
                $storedPlayer->setUpcomingOpponentPositionRank( $player['UpcomingOpponentPositionRank'] );
                $storedPlayer->setCurrentStatus( $player['CurrentStatus'] );
                $storedPlayer->setUpcomingSalary( $player['UpcomingSalary'] );

                $em->persist( $storedPlayer );
                $logData = [ 'action'   => 'Updated '.$logTitle,
                             'itemID'   => $player['PlayerID'],
                             'itemName' => $player['Name']
                ];
                $log[] = $logData;
            }
        }

        return ($log);
    }

    /**
     * @param Array $teamData
     * @param $repo
     * @param $em
     * @param String $logTitle
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function addTeamList( $teamData, $repo, $em, $log, $logTitle )
    {
        foreach ($teamData as $team) {
            // Get the current team in the list
            $criteria = array( 'teamID' => $team['TeamID'] );
            //var_dump($criteria);
            /** @var Team $storedTeam */
            $storedTeam = $repo->FindOneBy( $criteria );

            if ( ! $storedTeam) {
                //no stadium exists with the StadiumID passed
                //create a new entry
                /** @var Team $entry */
                $entry = new Team();
                $entry->setTeamKey( $team['Key'] );
                $entry->setTeamID( $team['TeamID'] );
                $entry->setPlayerID( $team['PlayerID'] );
                $entry->setCity( $team['City'] );
                $entry->setName( $team['Name'] );
                $entry->setConference( $team['Conference'] );
                $entry->setDivision( $team['Division'] );
                $entry->setFullName( $team['FullName'] );
                $entry->setStadiumID( $team['StadiumID'] );
                $entry->setByeWeek( $team['ByeWeek'] );
                $entry->setAvergageDraftPos( $team['AverageDraftPosition'] );
                $entry->setAverageDraftPosPPR( $team['AverageDraftPositionPPR'] );
                $entry->setHeadCoach( $team['HeadCoach'] );
                $entry->setOffensiveCoordinator( $team['OffensiveCoordinator'] );
                $entry->setDefensiveCoordinator( $team['DefensiveCoordinator'] );
                $entry->setSpecialTeamsCoach( $team['SpecialTeamsCoach'] );
                $entry->setOffensiveScheme( $team['OffensiveScheme'] );
                $entry->setDefensiveScheme( $team['DefensiveScheme'] );
                $entry->setUpcomingSalary( $team['UpcomingSalary'] );
                $entry->setUpcomingOpponentRank( $team['UpcomingOpponentRank'] );
                $entry->setUpcomingOpponentPositionRank( $team['UpcomingOpponentPositionRank'] );

                $em->persist( $entry );
                $logData = [ 'action' => 'Added New '.$logTitle , 'itemID' => $team['TeamID'], 'itemName' => $team['Name'] ];
                $log[]   = $logData;
            } else {
                $storedTeam->setTeamKey( $team['Key'] );
                $storedTeam->setPlayerID( $team['PlayerID'] );
                $storedTeam->setCity( $team['City'] );
                $storedTeam->setName( $team['Name'] );
                $storedTeam->setConference( $team['Conference'] );
                $storedTeam->setDivision( $team['Division'] );
                $storedTeam->setFullName( $team['FullName'] );
                $storedTeam->setStadiumID( $team['StadiumID'] );
                $storedTeam->setByeWeek( $team['ByeWeek'] );
                $storedTeam->setAvergageDraftPos( $team['AverageDraftPosition'] );
                $storedTeam->setAverageDraftPosPPR( $team['AverageDraftPositionPPR'] );
                $storedTeam->setHeadCoach( $team['HeadCoach'] );
                $storedTeam->setOffensiveCoordinator( $team['OffensiveCoordinator'] );
                $storedTeam->setDefensiveCoordinator( $team['DefensiveCoordinator'] );
                $storedTeam->setSpecialTeamsCoach( $team['SpecialTeamsCoach'] );
                $storedTeam->setOffensiveScheme( $team['OffensiveScheme'] );
                $storedTeam->setDefensiveScheme( $team['DefensiveScheme'] );
                $storedTeam->setUpcomingSalary( $team['UpcomingSalary'] );
                $storedTeam->setUpcomingOpponentRank( $team['UpcomingOpponentRank'] );
                $storedTeam->setUpcomingOpponentPositionRank( $team['UpcomingOpponentPositionRank'] );

                $em->persist( $storedTeam );

                $logData = [ 'action' => 'Updated  '.$logTitle , 'itemID' => $team['TeamID'], 'itemName' => $team['Name'] ];
                $log[]   = $logData;
            }
        }

        return $log;
    }

    /**
     * @param Array $stadiumData
     * @param $repo
     * @param $em
     * @param $log
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function addStadiumList( $stadiumData, $repo, $em, $log )
    {
        foreach ($stadiumData as $stadium) {
            // Get the current stadium in the list
            $criteria = array( 'stadiumID' => $stadium['StadiumID'] );
            //var_dump($criteria);
            /** @var Stadium $storedStadium */
            $storedStadium = $repo->FindOneBy( $criteria );

            if ( ! $storedStadium) {
                //no stadium exists with the StadiumID passed
                //create a new entry
                /** @var Stadium $entry */
                $entry = new Stadium();
                $entry->setStadiumID( $stadium['StadiumID'] );
                $entry->setName( $stadium['Name'] );
                $entry->setCity( $stadium['City'] );
                $entry->setState( $stadium['State'] );
                $entry->setCountry( $stadium['Country'] );
                $entry->setCapacity( $stadium['Capacity'] );
                $entry->setPlayingSurface( $stadium['PlayingSurface'] );
                $em->persist( $entry );
                $logData = [ 'action'   => 'Added New Stadium',
                             'itemID'   => $stadium['StadiumID'],
                             'itemName' => $stadium['Name']
                ];
                $log[]   = $logData;
            } else {
                $storedStadium->setStadiumID( $stadium['StadiumID'] );
                $storedStadium->setName( $stadium['Name'] );
                $storedStadium->setCity( $stadium['City'] );
                $storedStadium->setState( $stadium['State'] );
                $storedStadium->setCountry( $stadium['Country'] );
                $storedStadium->setCapacity( $stadium['Capacity'] );
                $storedStadium->setPlayingSurface( $stadium['PlayingSurface'] );
                $em->persist( $storedStadium );
                $logData = [ 'action'   => 'Updated Stadium',
                             'itemID'   => $stadium['StadiumID'],
                             'itemName' => $stadium['Name']
                ];
                $log[]   = $logData;
            }
        }

        return $log;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to handle your purposes for me is to create extended repository classes for your entities.

See [Symfony2 - Doctrine](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) documentation

In your case this might be:

```
namespace SomeBundle\Repository;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class PlayerRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @param Array  $players
     * @param        $playerRepo
     * @param        $em
     * @param Array  $log
     *
     * @param String $logTitle
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function addPlayerList($players, $log, $logTitle)
    {
        foreach ($players as $player) {
            // Get the current player in the list
            $criteria = array('playerID' => $player['PlayerID']);

            /** @var Player $storedPlayer */
            $storedPlayer = $this->findOneBy($criteria);

            if (!$storedPlayer) {
                $storedPlayer = new Player();

                $logData = [
                    'action'   => 'Added '.$logTitle,
                    'itemID'   => $player['PlayerID'],
                    'itemName' => $player['Name']
                ];
                $log[]   = $logData;
            } else {
                $logData = [
                    'action'   => 'Updated '.$logTitle,
                    'itemID'   => $player['PlayerID'],
                    'itemName' => $player['Name']
                ];
                $log[]   = $logData;
            }

            $storedPlayer->setPlayerID($player['PlayerID']);
            $storedPlayer->setTeam($player['Team']);
            $storedPlayer->setPlayerID($player['PlayerID']);
            $storedPlayer->setNumber($player['Number']);
            $storedPlayer->setFirstName($player['FirstName']);
            $storedPlayer->setLastName($player['LastName']);
            $storedPlayer->setPosition($player['Position']);
            $storedPlayer->setStatus($player['Status']);
            $storedPlayer->setHeight($player['Height']);
            $storedPlayer->setWeight($player['Weight']);
            //need to parse the date on this field
            $storedPlayer->setBirthDate($this->parseDate($player['BirthDate']));
            $storedPlayer->setCollege($player['College']);
            $storedPlayer->setExperience($player['Experience']);
            $storedPlayer->setFantasyPosition($player['FantasyPosition']);
            $storedPlayer->setActive($player['Active']);
            $storedPlayer->setPositionCategory($player['PositionCategory']);
            $storedPlayer->setName($player['Name']);
            $storedPlayer->setAge($player['Age']);
            $storedPlayer->setExperienceString($player['ExperienceString']);
            $storedPlayer->setBirthDateString($player['BirthDateString']);
            $storedPlayer->setPhotoUrl($player['PhotoUrl']);
            $storedPlayer->setByeWeek($player['ByeWeek']);
            $storedPlayer->setUpcomingGameOpponent($player['UpcomingGameOpponent']);
            $storedPlayer->setUpcomingGameWeek($player['UpcomingGameWeek']);
            $storedPlayer->setShortName($player['ShortName']);
            $storedPlayer->setAverageDraftPos($player['AverageDraftPosition']);
            $storedPlayer->setDepthPositionCategory($player['DepthPositionCategory']);
            $storedPlayer->setDepthPosition($player['DepthOrder']);
            $storedPlayer->setDepthDisplayOrder($player['DepthDisplayOrder']);
            $storedPlayer->setCurrentTeam($player['CurrentTeam']);
            $storedPlayer->setCollegeDraftTeam($player['CollegeDraftTeam']);
            $storedPlayer->setCollegeDraftYear($player['CollegeDraftYear']);
            $storedPlayer->setCollegeDraftRound($player['CollegeDraftRound']);
            $storedPlayer->setCollegeDraftPick($player['CollegeDraftPick']);
            $storedPlayer->setIsUndraftedFreeAgent($player['IsUndraftedFreeAgent']);
            $storedPlayer->setHeightFeet($player['HeightFeet']);
            $storedPlayer->setHeightInches($player['HeightInches']);
            $storedPlayer->setUpcomingOpponentRank($player['UpcomingOpponentRank']);
            $storedPlayer->setUpcomingOpponentPositionRank($player['UpcomingOpponentPositionRank']);
            $storedPlayer->setCurrentStatus($player['CurrentStatus']);
            $storedPlayer->setUpcomingSalary($player['UpcomingSalary']);

        }

        return ($log);
    }
}
```

Also on my own I'll rather created date parser class to parse date inside this repositories like

```
$date = (new CustomDateTimeParser('your fancy date string here'))->getDateTime();
```

Comment: Thats what i initially thought as it seems the easiest way, then i read in a lot of places that the repository should only be used for fetching data, not for adding or modifying existing data...

Comment: Actually, maybe. Probably you should just create a service converting array data to `Player` entity to make this flexible and replaceable if you intended to so. On this purpose you should just create a handling class and define a service. Look Service Container documentation http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html. It should be looking rather similar but you should also pass a `PlayerRepository` or `EntityManagerInterface` to it for fetching existing data.

Comment: Yes that sounds like good way of doing things, though i'm worried that i'm going to end up with hundreds of services all doing 1 small thing each, also thanks for the simplification of my addPlayerList method, its much more compact and manageable

Comment: Well, I see nothing bad in small classes with single responsibilty. A lot of things work the same way, I.e. Symfony Form Types or form Data Transformers